# Spring AMQP : CorrelationId changes between moment of sending and receiving a message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

While I was testing the send and receive methods which I created for my project I ran into a strange problem.
When I send a certain message using a correlationId that is based on a UUID object, the receiving party gets a slightly modified version of this correlationId (which cannot be deserialised).

On the sending side I do this:

```
MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();
properties.setCorrelationId(MessageSerializer.serialize(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
```

On my last test the UUID generated was: "**d4170243-9e7e-4c42-9168-f9da4debc5bb**"

This generates the following correlationId (when serialized):

```
[-84, -19, 0, 5, 116, 0, 36, 100, 52, 49, 55, 48, 50, 52, 51, 45, 57, 101, 55, 101, 45, 52, 99, 52, 50, 45, 57, 49, 54, 56, 45, 102, 57, 100, 97, 52, 100, 101, 98, 99, 53, 98, 98]
```

When I receive the message on the other side this id is slightly changed:

```
[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 0, 5, 116, 0, 36, 100, 52, 49, 55, 48, 50, 52, 51, 45, 57, 101, 55, 101, 45, 52, 99, 52, 50, 45, 57, 49, 54, 56, 45, 102, 57, 100, 97, 52, 100, 101, 98, 99, 53, 98, 98]
```

When using the RabbitMQ management plugin I noticed that the id already changed upon arrival at the queue.

[image]

Tracing my code on the sending side brings me to the send option of the RabbitTemplate class.

```
RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connection);
template.setExchange("amq.direct");
template.setRoutingKey("some.route");
template.send(message);
```

But I can't figure out what's causing this problem. I guess it's just me using the correlationId option the wrong way. Could someone help me out?

Appreciate it.

Comment: What are doing `MessageSerializer` ? The byte array generated is not strictly the byte array representation of the String#getByte()

Comment: The MessageSerializer is a custom created class which converts objects into a serialized byte array. The odd thing here is that it works perfectly for my payload objects. But not for my correlationId.

Comment: As the correlation id is finally converted back to a string when the client is constructing the network frame ([see the reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#class.basic)) I fear that your serialization introduces non ascii character which breaks the string. You may use a simple `UUID.randomUUID().toString().getByte()`

Comment: This seems to fix it. Although, I kinda want to know why it's not possible to first serialize it, and then send it. Just out of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation is the following:

1. You serialize the UUID string to a byte array
2. Your serialization prepends non ascii character to this array (`[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 0, 5, 116, 0, 36,...]`)
3. The [reference documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#class.basic) states that the correlation id is a shortstr. RabbitMQ client converts this byte array to a string using 
   `new String(yourArray , "UTF-8")`.
4. The non ascii character "corrupt" the conversion from byte[] to string

You can get the same result with the following code:

```
new String(MessageSerializer.serialize(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) , "UTF-8").getByte("UTF-8")
```

Which will return:

```
[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 0, 5, 116, 0, 36, 100, 52, 49, 55, 48, 50, 52, 51, 45, 57, 101, 55, 101, 45, 52, 99, 52, 50, 45, 57, 49, 54, 56, 45, 102, 57, 100, 97, 52, 100, 101, 98, 99, 53, 98, 98]
```